# Laravel language file generation

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, translation

What is the best way to automatically generate language files?

For example I have files located like this:
-/app
---/lang
------/en
---------global.php
---------tools.php
---------permissions.php
---------widgets.php

Is there any way how to clone all /lang/en files to 30 other languages?
 Folder '/lang' can also be in different locations not only in 'app'.

Comment: Why not copy/paste the  `/en` folder, and then rename them in the languages you want.